# text in columns doesn't line up, using bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 for my columns and I am trying to have two columns together, the one on the left to have a big text h4 title and the one on the right a small text comments count.

The problem is when adding the h4 tags around the title the "1 comments" bit seems to jump up to the top of the div it is in, I want it aligned to the bottom. Ideally I would want it aligned the same as the h4 and to the right.

Image to show: [image]

see the comments bit is higher than the bigger title text :(

```
<!-- main content -->
<div class="row">
    <!-- Articles -->
    <div class="col-md-9">

        <!-- notification -->
        <div class="alert alert-warning text-center">
            <a href="/admin.php">You have <span class="badge badge-important">3</span> admin items needing review!</a> 
        </div>

    <!-- new sales -->
    <div class="alert alert-success text-center">
        <strong>Latest Games On Sale:</strong> <a href="/sales/#86"><span class="label label-info">Steam</span> Sparkle 2 Evo</a>, <a href="/sales/#85"><span class="label label-info">Steam</span> Shadow Warrior Classic Redux</a>, <a href="/sales/#84"><span class="label label-info">Steam</span> Redshirt</a>, <a href="/sales/#83"><span class="label label-info">Steam</span> Gravity Badgers</a>  - <a href="/sales/">See all</a>
    </div>

    <div id="maincontent">

        <!-- Article -->
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-8"><h4><a href="/articles/sdasd-asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd.2121">Sdasd Asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</a></h4></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p class="small muted"><a href="/articles/sdasd-asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd.2121/#comments"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> 1 Comments</a></p></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, in Bootstrap an `<h4>` has a top margin of `10px` and a `<p>` has a top margin of `0`. Not that I am condoning inline styles, but this should give you an idea of how to get around it:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h4><a href="/articles/sdasd-asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd.2121">Sdasd Asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p class="small muted" style="margin-top:14px;"><a href="/articles/sdasd-asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd.2121/#comments"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> 1 Comments</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I used `14px` instead of `10px` to compensate for the difference in font-size. I also

Comment: Gah! That was it! Thanks!